# reloading META-INF/context.xml to ../conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml not working

Tags: java, tomcat6, catalina, context.xml, contextpath

I am trying to make a hot deployment. Database connection information are stored in my META-INF/context.xml.

When I drop the folder to my $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/, it tries to reload and then fails because it can't find the db connection informations. When I look within the ../conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml is it not in there.

Can someone give me some lead on it so I can find what might be wrong ?

(I don't think its a permission error since localhost is in 777 - for testing)

Comment: Are you redeploying a war or moving a folder to the webapps folder? And which version of Tomcat are you using

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work, the error were coming from two distinct issues

**First** : ../conf/Catalina/localhost should be owned by the tomcat user and not root or anything. By default it might not be the case according to the distribution.

**Second** : I was making a git pull within the webapps dir, and it was not working. What I am doing now is that I make the pull on /tmp and then move the directory to webapps. It is working fine, but I don't know why git pull make the operation fails, when a scp directly to this directory was working.

I hope it can help some of you,